# Are there any methods to initiate a database synchronization process in Plesk?

Tags: plesk

I removed a significant number of databases directly from the MySQL console, bypassing the Plesk interface. However, these deleted databases still appear in Plesk because their names were not removed from the 'psa' database.

Is there a straightforward method to eliminate these databases from Plesk or initiate a synchronization process? The alternative I have is to remove the rows from Plesk database.

Comment: As far as I know there is no command by which an automatic sync can be done.